# How can I accept/rejected incoming calls from android 5 and above?

Tags: android

I need to listen to incoming calls. I use the services for this. My activity opens when a call comes in. There are 2 buttons there. I want to accept an incoming call when one of this button is pressed. I tried many things but none of them worked. I would be glad if you show any help or resources.

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

    <application

        <activity android:name=".Activities.IncomingActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="ixa.whocalled.BroadcastReceiver.PhoneListenerBroad">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

> PhoneListenerBroad -- *BroadcastReceiver

```
public class PhoneListenerBroad extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Context c;
    private String outgoing;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        c = context;

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            outgoing = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            int state = 2;
            Intent intentPhoneCall = new Intent(c, IncomingActivity.class);
            intentPhoneCall.putExtra("incomingnumber", outgoing);
            intentPhoneCall.putExtra("state", state);
            intentPhoneCall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            c.startActivity(intentPhoneCall);

            Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        try {
            TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
            tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
        }

    }

    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public void onCallStateChanged(final int state, final String incomingNumber) {
            Handler callActionHandler = new Handler();
            Runnable runRingingActivity = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (state == 1) {
                        Intent intentPhoneCall = new Intent(c, IncomingActivity.class);
                        intentPhoneCall.putExtra("incomingnumber", incomingNumber);
                        intentPhoneCall.putExtra("state", state);
                        intentPhoneCall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        c.startActivity(intentPhoneCall);
                    }
                }
            };

            if (state == 1) {
                callActionHandler.postDelayed(runRingingActivity, 100);
            }

            if (state == 0) {
                callActionHandler.removeCallbacks(runRingingActivity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> IncomingActivity

```
public class IncomingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button Accept_Button, Decline_Button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming);

        Accept_Button = findViewById(R.id.ai_button01);
        Decline_Button = findViewById(R.id.ai_button02);

        Accept_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                acceptCall();
            }
        });

        Decline_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //empty
            }
        });
    }

    public void acceptCall() {

        Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

        Intent headSetUnPluggedintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        headSetUnPluggedintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
        headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("state", 0);
        headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("name", "Headset");
        try {
            sendOrderedBroadcast(headSetUnPluggedintent, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since API 23 (android 6) only proper way to do it is writing a [Replacement phone app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom#replacePhoneApp) and have your users chose it as default in system settings. Tricking device with mocked headset button press (like you have in your sample) no longer works on modern devices.

Comment: I tried this. As the default search application, I ask and accept in Activity. But the application does not appear as a phone application in the system settings. Do you have any information about this subject?

Comment: You don't have an `InCallService` implemented and in manifest.

Comment: I also added this and it works. So how can I accept an incoming call now?

Comment: In your `InCallService` override [`onCallAdded(Call)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService#onCallAdded(android.telecom.Call)) - that's where you receive a [`Call`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call) object that you use to determine who is calling and contains methods to accept/decline/mute/merge into conference etc. etc.

Comment: I am grateful to you for this information you provided. Thank you so much !